# php code is not running in dreamweaver while using wamp server

Tags: php, html, web, wamp, dreamweaver

i m working on a web site it has html and php when i run the php script in dreamweaver it is executing html code but not php.it is not accessing other html pages given in the following code

```
  </p>
<form method="post" action="" >
 <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>
    From:</p>
<select name="from">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>
    To:</p>
   <select name="To">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> </table>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['from']) and isset($_POST['To'])) {
$from = $_POST['from'] ;
$to = $_POST['To'] ;
$table = array($from, $to);

switch ($table) {
  case array ("Islamabad", "Lahore") :
  header("Location: flights.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Murree") :
  header("Location: hotels.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Muzaffarabad") :
 header("Location: videos.html");
 break;
//.....
//......
default:
echo "Your choice is nor valid !!";
}

}
?>
```

Comment: run url in your browser like `localhost/your folder name/ your file name`

Comment: [How to Create a PHP Website Using Dreamweaver 8](http://www.ehow.com/how_5886414_create-website-using-dreamweaver-8.html)

Comment: Is this even a .PHP page or .HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many problems!

From the PHP online Manual

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

So basically if you want to make the browser load a new page using `header()` you have to execute the `header()` before any other data ( HTML ) is sent to the browser. It is also a good idea to follow any `header()` with an `exit;`.

This might not be too difficult in your case as it looks to me like this code should go at the top of the script and not here in the middle of it anyway.